# delayed_job process same named queue on multiple workers one job at a time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I have different objects.

```
A  B  C
```

Each object has different jobs to process.

```
A  B  C
1  1  1
2  2  2
3  3  3
```

I got multiple delayed_job workers processing my jobs. I don't want to assign queues to them, so every worker can process jobs for every object, as there is no rule when which object will start a job.

So the queue can look like this

```
A3 B2 C3 C1 C2 A2 A1 B3
```

Any job of any object can be added to the queue at any time and can be processed by any worker, but, because of the objects characteristics there can only be one active job from any object at the same time.

Is this possible with delayed job?

Answer (score 0):

Delayed Job works in a FIFO-like basis according to the `run_at` time field. It will process whichever one was supposed to be run the longest ago. You can manually specify a `run_at` time to cater to your needs if you need things done in a specific order but DJ won't handle this for you.